# Fermat method for factorization - upper bound

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factoring

I'm reading through Crandall and Pomerance's "Prime Numbers: A Computational Perspective", and they give a brief description of the well known Fermat factorization method (Algorithm 5.1.1).

The algorithm takes an input $N$, and for each $a$ in the sequence $\lceil \sqrt{N} \rceil, \lceil \sqrt{N} \rceil +1, ...$ it calculates $c =a^2 -N$. If this number is a square, then we can write it as $c=b^2$ for some $b$, and so $N$ factors as $N = (a+b)(a-b)$. Indeed, all factorizations of odd, composite numbers occur in this way for some $a,b$, so we can be assured that the algorithm does terminate.

However, the authors note that the algorithm must terminate with a non-trivial factorization before we reach $$a = \left\lfloor \frac{N+9}{6} \right\rfloor,$$ (and this worst case only occurs when $N = 3p$ where $p$ is some prime) but I don't see why this should be the case.

Does anyone have any idea why the above should be true?

Comment: If $a-b=3$ then $N=(a+b)(a-b)=(a+(a-3))3=6a-9$, and solve for $a$.

Comment: @GregMartin That's great - that gives you one direction, but I was struggling with the other direction?

Comment: By "the other direction", do you mean "the worst case only occurs when $N=3p$"? That's a consequence of the fact that this factorization method finds the factorization $N=ab$ where $a$ and $b$ are closest together (and closest to $\sqrt N$).

Comment: @GregMartin I'm not sure I understand. Obviously the algorithm terminates. And we must have that $a - b < \sqrt{N}$. But why should that imply that $a \leq \left \lfloor \frac{N+9}{6} \right \rfloor$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $N$ is an odd composite number, and let $d$ is the smallest factor of $N$ that is greater than $\sqrt N$, so that $N=de$ (with $e=N/d$) is the factorization that the Fermat method will find.

The Fermat method finds this factorization as $N=(a+b)(a-b)$, so we have $a+b=d$ and $a-b=e=N/d$; solving for $a$ yields $a=\frac12(d+N/d)$.

The function $\frac12(d+N/d)$ is an increasing function of $d$ for $d>\sqrt N$. Therefore the worst case is when $d$ is as large as possible. That happens when $e$ is as small as possible, that is, when $e=3$. We conclude that $a = \frac12(d+N/d) \le \frac12(N/3+3) = \frac16(N+9)$.