# Show for some n Fermat’s method is faster than reverse trial division

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity, prime-factorization

One way to find a nontrivial
divisor of n is Fermat’s factorization method:

Suppose that we have an odd number n > 1 which we know is
composite and not a perfect square.

- Calculate $\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor$, the largest integer less than or equal to √n.
- Letting a run over $\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor$+ 1, $\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor$+ 2, $\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor$+ 3, ··· in turn:
- Calculate $\sqrt{a^2-n}$ and see whether it is an integer;
- Once we have $\sqrt{a^2-n}=b$ for some integer b, we know that $n = a^2 −b^2 = (a −b)(a + b)$, so we finish.

In assessing the time taken by Fermat’s method, it
is natural to compare it against “reverse trial division”, where
instead of testing divisibility of n by 2,3,4,···, we test divisibility of n by
$\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor, \lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor -1, \lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor-2,$ ···.

Explain why there are some values of n for which Fermat’s method would find a nontrivial divisor more quickly than
reverse trial division.

### Attempt

Let g(n) denote the largest divisor of n which is less
than $\sqrt{n}$, and let $h(n) = \frac{n}{g(n)}$.

Fermat’s method will try exactly
$$\frac{1}{2}(g(n) + h(n))-\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor$$
values of a before finishing, see [Fermat method for factorization - upper bound](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1883598/fermat-method-for-factorization-upper-bound/1884596#1884596)

“reverse trial division” takes $\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor - g(n) + 1$ steps to find g(n)

Comment: Since you only have to find SOME examples consider those cases where the fermat method needs only one step and show that reversed trial division takes much more.